# pandas dataframe style formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

In this example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':np.arange(10001,10007)}, 
    index=list(product(*[['A','B'],['a','b','c']])))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['Caps','Lower'])

df; df.style.format("{:,}")
```

when df is output to a Jupyter notebook, the values in column Caps are aligned to the top.  However, when `df.style.format("{:,}")` is output in a Jupyter notebook, the values in column Caps are centered.  Is there a way of forcing those values to be at the top? (i.e. they should be in the same line as `a` and not in the line as `b`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_table_styles` with `selector`:

```
df.style.format("{:,}").set_table_styles([{'selector':'th',
                                           'props':[('vertical-align','top')]}])
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, pandas displays the index labels a row below the column labels. For display purposes, you can get them on the same horizontal line by resetting the index.

```
df.reset_index()

   Caps Lower Value
0   A   a   10001
1   A   b   10002
2   A   c   10003
3   B   a   10004
4   B   b   10005
5   B   c   10006
```